# What is the physical meaning behind negative slope of laser characteristics?

Tags: semiconductor-physics, laser, photonics, laser-cavity

Sometimes I measure LIV curves of many semiconductor lasers with the same material and width and different cavity length.

There should be positive slope and intercept of Threshold current vs inverse cavity length dataset, and also positive intercept of Inverse External Differential Quantum Efficiency vs cavity length dataset.

Those qualities correspond to:

- intercept of threshold current vs inverse cavity length = transparency threshold current
- intercept of IEDQE vs cavith length = internal quantum efficiency
- slope of  IEDQE vs cavith length = internal loss

Sometimes those values from my data are negative. Obviously it means that something went wrong. But what can be physical reasons behind that?